# Does windows have performance counters to measure statistics of a dialup connection?

Tags: windows, performance, perfmon

Does windows have performance counters to measure statistics of a dialup connection? Opening up Perfmon I can see that it has a performance counter called "Network Interfaces" which can be used to collect stats on a chosen network interface (mostly LAN cards) but I cannot see my dial up connection in the list here. How do I go about collecting stats like bytes sent/received, speed etc for my dial up connection (which is actually a high speed broadband connection!) What is the perfmon query string I need to use?

Comment: I know, I know :) but its not really a dialup! The EVDO broadband modem I am using is connected as a USB dialup modem (USB in RS232 emulation mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally got a solution...the windows Dialup API is known as [RAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Access_Service) for some reason. Windows vista has several performance counters for RAS services. You can get the required information by reading these counters. Refer "[RAS total](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738450(WS.10).aspx)" and "[RAS Port](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738481(WS.10).aspx)".

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the IP helper API functions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073%28VS.85%29.aspx