# vb.net PerformanceCounters

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting to use PerformanceCounters via VB.NET 2010, mainly to check for broadband usage. Can someone point me in the right direction to use them, with some source code if possible.

Thank you.

Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The MSDN page for the PerformanceCounter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx#Y3331) has a VB.Net code sample for Performance Counters.

[According to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312077/does-windows-have-performance-counters-to-measure-statistics-of-a-dialup-connect), the performance counters you probably want to look at will be called `Network Interfaces`.

Here's a couple articles with some general information on counters:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734903.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx#XSLTsection133121120120 (older article, tho might still have some valid info on the counters available)